# Unable to install vue-property-decorator or vue-class-component, when created project using vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have created a Vue3 project using Vite. When Vite is used I am unable to install vue-property-decorator or vue-class-component. It says it is unable to resolve dependency tree. Errors are attached below:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: new-vite-project@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.32
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.2.25" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-class-component
npm ERR!   peer vue-class-component@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/zohaib/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zohaib/.npm/_logs/2022-04-13T20_02_35_956Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 4):

`vue-class-component` still **doesn't officially support Vue 3**.
It has a Release Candidate (RC) version though, but it may **not be ready for production**.

See this comment: [vue-class-component issue #406](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406#issuecomment-1082817638)

To install it:

```
npm install vue-class-component@8.0.0-rc.1 vue-property-decorator@10.0.0-rc.3
```